# What is the different between Navigation.findNavController(it) and NavHostFragment.findNavController()?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I want to know the different between `Navigation.findNavController(it)` and `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)`. Basically both are doing the same thing but don't know the exact location which these methods have to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [Navigate to a destination documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate):

> To retrieve the NavController for a **fragment, activity, or view,** use one of the following methods

If you have only have a reference to a `View`, use `Navigation.findNavController()`. As per [its Javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/Navigation#findNavController(android.view.View)), it goes up the View hierarchy to find the `NavController`. This would be appropriate in `onClick()` listeners or other cases where you are interacting with a View that was created by a `Fragment` destination.

If you have a reference to the `Activity` and the id of the nav host, use `Navigation.findNavController(Activity, @IdRes int)`. As per [its Javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/Navigation#findNavController(android.app.Activity,%20int)), "this is a convenience wrapper around `Navigation.findNavController(View)`" - it just calls `findViewById()` for you.

When you have a reference to a `Fragment`, you can use `NavHostFragment.findNavController()`. As per [its Javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/fragment/NavHostFragment#findNavController(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)), it walks up the `Fragment` hierarchy (i.e., calling `getParentFragment()` until it finds a `NavHostFragment`) *before* calling through to `Navigation.findNavController(View)`.

In all cases, you get the same `NavController` back, so use whatever is convenient.