# how do i fix "Unresolved reference: nav_host_fragment_content_main" in my android app kotlin project

Tags: android, kotlin

I created a basic app by following a tutorial on the android documentation using kotlin. When i tried to run the project, I encounter this error:

> Unresolved reference: nav_host_fragment_content_main

This is the content of the MainActivity.Kt file.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

    binding.fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
// for 'this' parameter check link below

val findNavController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
findNavController.navigate(YourFragmentDirections.actionYourFragmentToAnotherFragment())
```

[What is the different between Navigation.findNavController(it) and NavHostFragment.findNavController()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553396/what-is-the-different-between-navigation-findnavcontrollerit-and-navhostfragme)